# Why does the executable in this rubygem require its development dependencies

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I have an executable in my gem [`activefacts-compositions`](https://github.com/cjheath/activefacts-compositions). Running the gem requires the development dependencies, not just the runtime ones. This executable is not a development tool, but is the main reason for the gem to exist - so it should not require a development install.

To test it:

```
gem install activefacts-compositions
schema_compositor —help
```

results in:

```
Could not find gem 'activefacts (>= 1.8, ~> 1) ruby' in any of the gem sources listed in your Gemfile or available on this machine.
Run `bundle install` to install missing gems.
```

then:

```
gem install --dev activefacts-compositions
schema_compositor —help
```

results in:

```
Available compositors:
    binary
    relational

Available generators:
    ruby
    sql
    sql/server
    summary
    validate
```

Comment: Post your Gemfile.lock. I'll bet one of your runtime dependencies is pulling it in.

Comment: Just tried. The executable depends on `rspec` and `activefacts` gems. After installing these two, `schema_compositor` throws the following output: `fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git
There was an error while trying to write to Gemfile.lock. It is likely that you need to allow write permissions for the file at path: /var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/activefacts-compositions-1.9.6/Gemfile.lock`

Answer (score 0):

The answer (provided by Eric Hodel on IRC thanks @drbrain) is that my executable calls:

```
require 'bundler/setup'
```

From the days when bundler wasn't as good as it is now. Delete that and all is dandy.